# OOP C# - How do I add info from class address, to info in class Participant, through ParticipantManager to show in ListBox

Tags: c#, oop, listbox, tostring

I have a class Address that contains info about a participants adress, in turn I have a class Participant that holds the rest of the info about the participant. The participants are stored in a list in a class called ParticipantManager.

I have some trouble with getting MainForm to show the information about the adress, it only shows first name and last name that is stored in the class participant. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string strOut = string.Format("{0, -25} {1, -8} {2, -10} {3}", street, zipcode, city, GetCountryString());

        return strOut;


    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string strOut = string.Format("{0, -20} {1}", firstName, lastName, address.ToString());
        return strOut;

    }
    public string[] GetParticipantsInfo()
    {
        string[] strInfoString = new string[participants.Count];

        int i = 0;
        foreach (Participant ParticipantObj in participants)
        {
            strInfoString[i++] = ParticipantObj.ToString();
        }

        return strInfoString;
    }


    private void UpdateGUI()
    {
        string[] strInfo = eventManager.Participants.GetParticipantsInfo();

        if(strInfo != null)
        {
            listGuests.Items.Clear();
            listGuests.Items.AddRange(strInfo);
            lblNumOP.Text = listGuests.Items.Count.ToString();

        }
```

I expect the address to be shown in the listBox next to the first name and last name

Comment: The methods are not static which means you need an instance of the class and the same instance is need where you fill the list and get the list. I do not know if GetParticipantsInfo() is static.